# git log only using --follow shows a commit but file name is the same

Tags: git

When I do

```
git log --follow --name-only -- laravel/resources/views/tickets/stage-options.blade.php
```

it shows:

> ```
> commit c946893acef5b626e01256aa98da7e7ae874d96b
> Author: coder
> Date:   Tue Apr 10 13:00:09 2018 +0100
>
>     add bulk sub tasks breaks if url has parameters
>
> laravel/resources/views/tickets/stage-options.blade.php
>
> commit 8e00c11ef749858a874a7ae4438032e03db5563b
> Author: coder
> Date:   Fri Apr 6 13:02:47 2018 +0100
>
>     get rid of useless buttons in stage/task side popups
>
> laravel/resources/views/tickets/stage-options.blade.php
> ```

but if i do:

```
git log --name-only -- laravel/resources/views/tickets/stage-options.blade.php
```

it shows:

> ```
> commit 8e00c11ef749858a874a7ae4438032e03db5563b
> Author: coder
> Date:   Fri Apr 6 13:02:47 2018 +0100
>
>     get rid of useless buttons in stage/task side popups
>
> laravel/resources/views/tickets/stage-options.blade.php
> ```

the earliest commit without `--follow` is april 6th, and with `--follow` there is an extra commit on april 10th.  but as you can see, the filename is the same on both.  Why might this be?

Comment: Is the repository publicly accessible (for further investigation)?

Comment: Note that by default, Git shows commits in "commit date" order if it's looking down several branches. It might help to add `--graph` and `--pretty=fuller` to the options, although with this particular issue I'd like to look at the repository itself, as @Jubobs suggests.

Comment: OSX filenames aren’t case sensitive. It’s possible someone on Linux/Windows renamed the file changing only case, and that’s not visible to you.